# Scott Aaronson tests for faulty P $\neq$ NP proofs; separating 2-SAT

Tags: logic, computer-science, computational-complexity

In his blog post on the [Eight Signs A Claimed P $\neq$ NP Proof Is Wrong](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=458)”, Scott Aaronson indicates in his first test that the proof fails to distinguish 2-SAT and other elementary problems known to be in P.

Question: Is there any complexity measure whatsoever, not just time complexity, that can distinguish 2-SAT from Clique, for example?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Cross-post this on MathOverload where the pros are.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: many thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  it is actually MathOverthrow